# How to render Boostrap templates using with handlebarsjs

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, handlebars.js, bootstrap-4

Hi There i'm trying to render a bootstrap template with handlebars (i'm using Express as a server), and it just doesn't render properly, the carousel slider and the Navbar logo are not rendered at all.

> PS: I added all dependencies that are needed Bootstrap
>   4/jquery/popper..

Comment: Please post a minimal code examples from your project, to debug this. A screenshot might help as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if you're correctly loading the bootstrap dependencies.

You need to load the CSS CDN at the start of your HTML file and load the js dependencies at the end of your HTML file.

Ideally, It should work something like that:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/yourStyles.css">
    <title>You title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Besides that, as you're using handlebars I think that you probably wanna do is create partials for loading such dependencies so you don't need to repeat the code all along with your other views.

I am not sure that is the right pattern, but in my project I create one partial for htmlStart, where I have everything I need my pages to have until the content(as the content is gonna differ from page to page) and another partial for htmlEnd, loading everything I needed to finish the page, as footer, bootstrap script and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to properly configure webpack to build your package.json front-end dependencies just use them directly in your **.hbs** file. Like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>{{title}}</h1>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```